# DefaultErrorHandler is not configurable If @RetryableTopic used for retry and DLT handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, retry-logic

Spring boot version : 2.7.6
Spring kafka version : 2.8.11

Issue:

I was trying to handle the deserialization issues in code. To handle such issues in code, I created my own class by extending

```
DefaultErrorHandler
```

and overriding the `public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener) {}` 
Sample code as below

```
public class CustomDefaultErrorHandler extends DefaultErrorHandler {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomDefaultErrorHandler.class);
    @Override
    public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener) {
        manageException(thrownException, consumer);
    }

    private void manageException(Exception ex, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        log.error("Error polling message: " + ex.getMessage());
        if (ex instanceof RecordDeserializationException) {
            RecordDeserializationException rde = (RecordDeserializationException) ex;
            consumer.seek(rde.topicPartition(), rde.offset() + 1L);
            consumer.commitSync();
        } else {
            log.error("Exception not handled");
        }
    }
}
```

If I use the @RetryableTopic along with @KafkaListener

```
@RetryableTopic(listenerContainerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", backoff = @Backoff(delay = 8000, multiplier = 2.0),
        dltStrategy = DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR
        , traversingCauses = "true", autoCreateTopics = "true", numPartitions = "3", replicationFactor = "3",
        fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.MULTIPLE_TOPICS, include = {RetriableException.class, RecoverableDataAccessException.class,
        SQLTransientException.class, CallNotPermittedException.class}
)
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topic.name}", groupId = "order", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", id = "OTR")
public void consumeOTRMessages(ConsumerRecord<String, PayloadsVO> payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName) throws JsonProcessingException {
    logger.info("Payload :{}", payload.value());
    payloadsService.savePayload(payload.value(), pegasusTopicName);

}
```

What I saw in debugging the code, @RetryableTopic has its own DefaultErrorHandler configurations in

```
ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer
```

and it stops my custom handler and deserialization process wont stop on issue.

Can you please suggest any way since I wanted to use annotations for retry process in my code

I tried to configured my own implementation of

```
DefaultErrorHandler
```

by extending it and configured in

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite involved, but you should be able to override the `RetryTopicComponentFactory` bean and override `listenerContainerFactoryConfigurer()` to return your custom error handler.

That said, deserialization exceptions will go straight to the DLT anyway.

BTW, calling `commitSync()` here is worthless because there were no records returned by the `poll()`.

Comment: I found RetryTopicComponentFactory class is available in spring-kafka version 2.9.2 and then I required to explicitly set this version in my POM. currently I am using spring boot 2.7.6 version and it has Spring-kafka 2.8.11, alright does this mean I have to use explicit spring kafka version.?

Comment: Yes, 2.9 was released after Boot 2.7, but is compatible with it; simply override Boot's prescribed version.